# Hibernate Logical Name vs Physical Name

Tags: database, hibernate

I am just starting with Hibernate and referring to hibernate documentation for reference. As mentioned in [hibernate-documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#naming) :

> The first stage is determining a proper logical name from the domain model mapping. A logical name can be either explicitly specified by the user (using @Column or @Table e.g.) or it can be implicitly determined by Hibernate through an ImplicitNamingStrategy contract.
>
> Second is the **resolving of this logical name to a physical name** which is defined by the PhysicalNamingStrategy contract.

Can someone please explain what is the difference between **logical name** and **physical name** in JPA/Hiberbnate/DB context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- logical name is the name that stored in java / hibernate
- physical name is the name in the database

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a bit ? Because what I experienced is if I am providing a logical name using say `@Column` or `@Table` annotations in my **java** code, the same is reflected in the database as well (in the form of table/column names).

And in what use-cases one can choose to have different physical and logical names?

Comment: You need to implement [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#PhysicalNamingStrategy) to make different physical and logical names

Comment: Apologies for the confusion, what I meant was in what scenarios one would want to have different physical and logical names becuase (quoting the same section):  _JPA defines no separation between logical and physical name_ . I know we can override `toPhysicalTableName` method of `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` for thatt

Comment: It's in the link :)  _Many organizations define rules around the naming of database objects (tables, columns, foreign-keys, etc). The idea of a PhysicalNamingStrategy is to help implement such naming rules without having to hard-code them into the mapping via explicit names._

Comment: ahh. . missed that. . Thanks Erwin